# dynamically add attribute to child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamical slider. And trying to add `tabindex="-1"` attribute to child when it's parent `LI` element has `aria-hidden="true"` attribute.

This code is what I am want to be in DOM

```
<ul class="slider">
  <li aria-hidden="true"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Link</a></li>
  <li aria-hidden="true"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Link</a></li>
  <li aria-hidden="false"><a href="#" tabindex="0">Link</a></li>
  <li aria-hidden="false"><a href="#" tabindex="0">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help

Comment: did you tried any code so far??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this JQuery code:

```
$('li[aria-hidden=true]').children().attr('tabindex', '-1');
```

It selects all `li` elements that have an attribute `aria-hidden=true` and then sets the attribute `tabindex` to '-1' for all children;
Edit:
Fixed the 'dot' typo.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask u 1 more question? If the attribute is  dynamical how do I change the code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what you mean. The Jquery I showed contains strings (in quotes), as selectors, you can of course build your own strings. If that isn't the answer, please ask a new question in StackOverflow, so more people can answer.